# How can I use jquery to pull some php from a .php file and run it on another page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

With jquery, I'm attempting to pull information from a .php file and run it in another html page.

To try this out I attempted to use this example:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-get.htm

The .php file would include:

```
    <?php
    if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        echo "Welcome ". $name;
    }
    ?>
```

================ The html page code includes:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // has the google object loaded?
    if (window.google && window.google.load) {
        google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    } else {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://joecrawford.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        $('#test').css({'border':'2px solid #f00'});
    };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <!-- -------- Test jQuery -------- -->
            <p id="test">hello jQuery</p>
            <!-- -------- /end Test jQuery -------- -->

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#driver").click(function(event){
              $.get( 
                 "/testing.php",
                 { name: "Zara" },
                 function(data) {
                    $('#stage').html(data);
                 }

              );
          });
       });
    </script>
     <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
       <div id="stage" >
              STAGE
       </div>
       <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
    </body>
```

The jquery library has successfully loaded, as per the "test result".

For some reason, the contents of the "testing.php" file are not being pulled... almost as though it's linked incorrectly. Is the file linked improperly? (both the .php and .html files are in the same folder)

I even tried doing something simple, like an echo statement in the php, but still nothing was pulled from the file and published to the html page.

There might be a simple fix that you see. I appreciate your time and energy in helping me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `"/testing.php"` to `"testing.php"`

Comment: but wait this already works. I just tried your code on my server and it works like you expect. so whats the issue that you are facing?

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2? That's almost three years old. Use an up to date version of the library.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code. What does your browser's JavaScript console say? Are there any errors? What does your browser's network debug tool say? Is the request being made? Is it going to the right URL? Is it getting a 200 response? Is the content of the response what you expect?

Comment: @HankyPanky, it does not work for me. The files are hosted from a folder on my computer and are being displayed in the browser. (the fact that it's hosted on my computer should have nothing to do with it, right?) 

Ultimately, this example was meant to determine a simple way to call a php file...

The ultimate outcome has to do with a Magento site I am working on:

Comment: i see, just to confirm you are loading this html file via http right? and not just double click and open?

Comment: Your code, as it is, works fine for me

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of my ultimately ideal outcome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148420/determine-browser-width-with-jquery-then-call-one-out-of-two-php-files-from

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this: `$('#stage').load('testing.php?name=Zara');`

Comment: But that would not pass the `name` parameter to the php page?

Comment: Why should this work if the code in the question does not? Writing new code to do the same job as the original code doesn't solve the problem as it is likely to have the same underlying problem. This doesn't even do the same job as the URL has changed and the query string data has been discarded.

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of my ultimately ideal outcome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148420/determine-browser-width-with-jquery-then-call-one-out-of-two-php-files-from ... Thanks again for you time, energy, and efforts! It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The files are hosted from a folder on my computer

This gives you two problems:

1. Browsers put pretty strict restrictions on what webpages loaded from the filesystem can do, loading other files via XMLHttpRequest is forbidden
2. PHP is a server side technology, it needs a server to work (in this context)

Host your site on a webserver. It can be one you run locally, then you can access the site via `http://localhost/etc`

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of my ultimately ideal outcome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148420/determine-browser-width-with-jquery-then-call-one-out-of-two-php-files-from ... Thanks again for you time, energy, and efforts! It is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery.ajax instead. Here is your HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// has the google object loaded?
if (window.google && window.google.load) {
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
} else {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://joecrawford.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"><\/script>');
}
window.onload = function() {
    $('#test').css({'border':'2px solid #f00'});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <!-- -------- Test jQuery -------- -->
        <p id="test">hello jQuery</p>
        <!-- -------- /end Test jQuery -------- -->

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.ajax({ 
             url: "testing.php",
             data: { name: "Zara" },
             success: function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
             }

          });
      });
   });
</script>
 <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
   <div id="stage" >
          STAGE
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
```

Comment: Why should that work when the original does not? Why have you changed the URL?

Comment: Because URL is the prime issue here. Changing it does the job.

Comment: How do you know that the URL is the prime issue? If the URL is the prime issue why didn't you say that in your answer instead of telling the OP to use `.ajax` instead of `.get`?

Comment: Because I tried it on my local. BTW why did you tell OP to use newer jquery library. How do you know that's the issue?

Comment: Trying it on your local system doesn't prove anything about the URL being wrong - you don't know where he put the files. I recommended using a newer version of the jQuery library because (in general) using out of date libraries is Not A Good Idea … but I didn't suggest it would solve the problem, I made that recommendation in a *comment* not an answer.

Comment: Well OP will downvote me if solution doesn't work for him. And instead of recommending stuff if you try to resolve the issue, it might help people better.

Comment: I am trying to resolve the issue. I gave a large paragraph of questions prodding for debugging in the comments.

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of my ultimately ideal outcome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148420/determine-browser-width-with-jquery-then-call-one-out-of-two-php-files-from ... Thanks again for you time, energy, and efforts! It is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather do the following...

```
<?php
    if( $_GET["name"] )
    {
        $name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['name']));
        echo "Welcome ". $name;
    }
?>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
        $.load( "testing.php?name=Zara, function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
             }

          );
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of my ultimately ideal outcome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148420/determine-browser-width-with-jquery-then-call-one-out-of-two-php-files-from ... Thanks again for you time, energy, and efforts! It is appreciated.